# Synchronizing on Egit. Everything is outgoing

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm using Egit on Eclipse.

I have cloned a project and I have imported it on Eclipse. I haven't done any change yet.

When I do "Pull" or "Fetch from Upstream" it says, as expected, "Nothing to update - everything up to date". However, when I do "Synchronize Workspace", all files appears "Outgoing", this is, marked with the black arrow. Whichever file I open in "Compare Editor" appears with one big difference which covers all the lines.

Just in case, I have checked that I have configured "text file line delimiter" and "text file encoding" in the same way that the creator of the project.

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles upon this question: I had the same problem when cloning a repository for the first time. For me, closing and restarting Eclipse has proven to repair that problem (repeatedly).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is solved making "Untrack", "Add to Index" and "Overwrite" successively, but anyways, I feel that is a suspicious behaviour.